# On studying web programming

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

What are the best resource to study the following: JavaScript, AJAX, CodeIgniter
Smarty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OReilly's *Javascript: The Definitive Guide, 5th Edition* (or later)
[http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-David-Flanagan/dp/0596101996/ref=dp_ob_title_bk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101996)

Answer (score 5):

Though perhaps not suited as a first book on JavaScript, I recommend

[JavaScript - the Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748) by Douglas Crockford. It will keep you from doing some dumb things.

Answer (score 4):

Digging into JQuery and using it is a great way to crash course into something more complex than "hello world" with javascript

In general, you will learn a lot if you just do stuff in this fashion.

1. Pick a feature you think is cool
2. Google it to find a solution
3. Instead of copy/paste, make sure you understand what the code actually does, and how
4. Change it in some way to make sure your understanding is correct \
5. Use Google to find out why your changes failed
6. Rinse/Repeat

Answer (score 3):

CodeIgniter has a great [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/). Just download CI and start building a simple web site, using the guide as a starting point and reference.

Also, I would recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for your JavaScript and AJAX - it will make your life much easier!

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely take a visit to http://www.w3schools.com.

Answer (score 1):

Net Tuts has some of the best tutorials on the net.

http://net.tutsplus.com/?s=codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

You might find these questions interesting:

- [Good JavaScript Books?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/good-javascript-books)
- [Best book to learn web development for a professional developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594159/best-book-to-learn-web-development-for-a-professional-developer)
- [Where should i start before using codeigniter with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988124/where-should-i-start-before-using-codeigniter-with-php)